# Pass arg to docker container with compose

Tags: docker, minecraft

I use docker compose to create and start my containers. I would like to create a minecraft container with a --noconsole arg. Like this :

```
docker run -it -d --name spigot -e EULA=TRUE -e TYPE=SPIGOT itzg/minecraft-server nogui --noconsole
```

I've no idea how to add the --noconsole parameter in the compose file.

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know incase of minecraft if it works or not but can you try this once `docker-compose exec -T --noconsole` with and without -T . This is  how I pass the args to already running container after  running it with docker-compose . Run your container and than after use the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments after the image name in `docker run` are not docker arguments, they are passed as the command to run inside the container. You need to define the command for the image you are running inside your compose file. The resulting syntax looks like:

```
command: "nogui --noconsole"
```

See the compose file documentation for more details: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command